# convert Mathematica LaTeX to regular LaTeX

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I often want to copy formulas from Mathematica into a LaTeX document. Mathematica has a “copy as LaTeX” function, but it gives me not really the results that I want:

```
\text{Cos}[x]+\text{Sin}[x]
```

I rather would like to have the following:

```
\cos(x)+\sin(x)
```

I tried to use regular expressions in Python, which kind of work, but I cannot match matching brackets or parenteses. That would be very handy, since there could be anything in the cosine.

What would be a doable way to convert this?

Comment: Mods -- this might be a better question for the [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com). See [related TeX questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`TeXForm[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html).

```
In[1] := TeXForm[Cos[x] + Sin[x]]

Out[1]//TeXForm=
         \sin (x)+\cos (x)
```

Comment: Okay, that solves the problem directly :-)